# Dynamic column value to columns name mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table like following, i have almost 100+ questions and more than 30,000 students:

```
StudentId | Questions  | QID| Answer  | View   | 
1         | YourGender | 1  | Male    | Gender | 
2         | YourGender | 1  | Female  | Gender |
1         | YourAge?   | 2  | 23      | Age    | 
2         | YourAge    | 2  | 21      | Age    |
```

I need table like followings:

```
StudentId | YourGender  | YourAge?
    1     | Male        | 23  
    2     | Female      | 21
```

My questions are randomly add/modify/del, so I want everything should work dynamically, when questions added or deleted I need not to change anything on my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it on this way:

Select all distinct StudentId, and join its with two subqueries, one with all answers about `Gender` and another with all answers about `Age`, both grouped by StudentId.

```
select    distinct q.StudentId,
          g.Answer as YourGender,
          a.Answer as YourAge
from      questions q
left join (
           select   StudentId, Answer
           from     questions
           where    View = 'Gender'
           group by StudentId
          ) g
on         g.StudentId = q.StudentId
left join (
           select   StudentId, Answer
           from     questions
           where    View = 'Age'
           group by StudentId
          ) a
on         a.StudentId = q.StudentId
;
```

This is the result:

```
| StudentId | YourGender | YourAge |
|-----------|------------|---------|
| 1         | Male       | 23      |
| 2         | Female     | 21      |
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/XPNAT23300

Comment: in this code, if i add/del/modify my any of questions, i will need to change this code every time and i have almost 100+ questions, thanks for your suggestion